# Does TSpeedButton supports 32bit glyphs?

Tags: delphi, alpha, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to load the `Glyph` of a `TSpeedButton` at runtime from a `TImageList`. In that image list I have 32bit bitmaps (RGB + Alpha), not 24bit simple RGB. I load the glyph with the following code:

```
 SpeedButton.Glyph.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsClear;
 SpeedButton.Glyph.PixelFormat:= pf32bit;
 SpeedButton.NumGlyphs:= 2;
 SpeedButton.Glyph.SetSize(ImgList.Width * 2, ImgList.Height);
 ImgList.Draw(SpeedButton.Glyph.Canvas, 0, 0, idxCancelRed);
 ImgList.Draw(SpeedButton.Glyph.Canvas, Pics.ImgList, 0, idxCancelRedDis);
```

The transparency it's ok, but the edges of the drawings (where the alpha color is present) are darker as if the alpha value it's not used, and that pixels are blended with some black background... Am I missing something or the `TSpeedButton` does not support alpha bitmaps (in which case I have to start making my own speed button control) ?

Comment: You can give PngComponents (available via GetIt) a try. It has a TPngSpeedButton where you can directly load the PNG into the PngImage property.

Comment: Very few things in the native VCL support alpha channels in bitmaps. Typically, you need to use 3rd party components or owner drawing to handle alpha.

Comment: @UweRaabe TPngSpeedButton does exactly what I want. :) Thanks !

Comment: @RemyLebeau too bad... So many years of development, and they still don't integrate alpha in standard controls... That thing with the lower-left pixel for transparency is hilarious...

Comment: - *"where the alpha color is present"* - Do you mean "where there should be partial transparency"? (alpha is not a color).

Comment: `TSpeedButton` is not a *standard control*. It's a non-standard control that has been around since Delphi 1. A *standard control* like `TButton` or `TToolbarButton` both support alpha transparency in their images. Most modern programs have abandoned `TSpeedButton` long ago - it's most likely still around because of legacy reasons. If you don't like it's design, you should start using something else that wasn't developed in the '90s instead.

Comment: Note that a graphic that has been drawn over a solid background won't look correct after it has been transparentized (?) over a contrasting background. That is if you're comparing the picture on a white speed button with the picture on your favorite image viewer which draws a black background, you may be misdiagnosing the problem.